# Transfer post data from one web application(www.example1.com) to another web application(www.example2.com)

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have two web applications(webapp1, webapp2).

In webapp1, I am having one button and two texboxes(textbook1, textbook 2).
On click button of webapp1, opens one form present at webapp2 in new tab.

form of webapp2 contains 2 textboxes(textbox3, textbox4).
After submitting form is it possible to assign values of textbox3, textbox4 to textbox1, textbox2(of webapp1) respectively?

I tried by using cors, jsonp but I failed.
The main problem is calling form of webapp2 from webapp1 & receiving data at webapp1. Sample code of WebApp1 is as given below:

```
// WebApp1 code
<div style="padding-top:30px">
   <a href="http://{webapp2}/test/Controller/Method" target="_blank">Add</a>
</div>
<div style="padding-top:30px">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtbox1" name="txtbox1">
</div>
<div style="padding-top:30px">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtbox2" name="txtbox2">
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$('a').on('click', function (event) {
    // Prevent default link behavior
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    var targetAttr = $(this).attr('target');
    var linkHref = $(this).attr('href');

    var win = window.open(linkHref, "window2", '', true);
    var pollTimer = window.setInterval(function () {
        try {
            alert(win.document.URL);
            console.log(win.document.URL);
            if (win.document.URL.indexOf("webapp1/Test/Index") != -1) {
                window.clearInterval(pollTimer);
                // url also contains encrypted data sent by webapp2
                var url = win.document.URL;
                win.close();
                debugger;
            }
        }
        catch (e) {

        }
    }, 500);
});
```

Is anyone know how to solve this problem .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can call a website like this http://www.microsoft.com?textbox1=avalue&textbox2=anothervalue  .  You can pass arguments in the query string and consume the arguments in the receiving website.

Comment: @kblau Thanks for your help. But it's not about just calling the website. button of webapp1 calls form of webapp2 using jquery ajax. Response sent by Webapp2 has to  be received at calling location i.e in jquery ajax success or done function of webapp1